# grouped bar chart resizing the plot area

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

in the below chart i want to resize the plot area so the column labels to be clear, any advise?

```
plt.rcParams['font.size'] = 10
plt.figure(figsize=(30,20))
labels = dog_breed_retweet_mean.index.str.replace('_', ' ').str.title()
dog_breed_retweet_mean = dog_breed_retweet_mean.sort_values(ascending=False).head(11)
dog_breed_favorite_mean = dog_breed_favorite_mean.sort_values(ascending=False).head(11)
x = np.arange(len(labels))  # the label locations
width = 0.35  # the width of the bars

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
rects1 = ax.bar(x - width/2, dog_breed_retweet_mean, width, label='Retweet')
rects2 = ax.bar(x + width/2, dog_breed_favorite_mean, width, label='Favorite')

# Add some text for labels, title and custom x-axis tick labels, etc.
ax.set_ylabel('Mean Scores')
ax.set_title('Scores grouped by Dog breed')
ax.set_xticks(x)
ax.set_xticklabels(labels)
ax.legend()



#fig.tight_layout()

plt.show()
```

group chart

Comment: i tried to uncomment fig.tight_layout() but no effect

Comment: Well, `tight_layout()` is just meant to fit all labels and titles nicely into the plot area. It should work perfectly in your case.  If you want to change the figsize, you need `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(..., ...))`. Note that `plt.subplots()` creates a new figure, replacing the one created by `plt.figure()`.